# sysbench anomaly: ubuntu server vs debian

Tags: server, performance, debian, benchmarks

im running the following commands in two VPS with the same hardware (1gb ram 1core):

```
sysbench --test=memory run
sysbench --test=memory --memory-oper=write run
```

The results Ive got were 10 seconds for ubuntu server, and 35 seconds for debian... How can be such difference in the same hardware?

Ive tested it in digitalocean, linode and cloud.io. In all VPS providers got the similar results. All benchmark parameters were the same, only OS changed.

Anyone knows why there is such performance difference? Have real world applications such difference in performance?

[Memory results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1FvH.png)

[CPU results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jqoq1.png)

> uname -a:
>
> **Ubuntu;** Linux utest 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> **Debian:** Linux dtest 4.9.0-5-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Could the elapsed time differences be due to configuration differences? The relevant numbers would be ops/second and/or MB/Sec. Also, what kernel versions are being used in each case?

Comment: Added outputs & uname. Hardware is exactly the same :/

Comment: "The results Ive got were 10 seconds for ubuntu server, and 35 seconds for debian... How can be such difference in the same hardware?"  Unless you want Ubuntu to go for 35 seconds the problem is with the Debian version and that makes it off topic. Please use http://unix.stackexchange.com/ Do note the kernel version is different. Maybe there is a module not loaded in the Debian setup.

Comment: Comparing Ubuntu's performance with another distro like Debian or Fedora is off topic at Ask Ubuntu, but this question is on topic at [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of sysbench being used is different in each case. While the debain one is taking 1.3377 times longer per operation, it is also doing 2.6596 times the number of operations, for an expected total of 3.56 longer, which is consistent with your results.

So, why the 1.34 times longer per operation? Different kernel versions and different sysbench versions and possibly different amounts of free memory available for the tests, before swap is used. I wouldn't be concerned until the conditions were more similar between the two tests.